# Chartkick - Stacked counting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, charts, chartkick

Im working with Chartkick library right now.. But i really want to show stacked number of counted subscriber every day.

**This is my call to get chart with stats:**

```
<%= area_chart User.with_role(:subscriber, Page.find_by_page_id(current_user.selected_page)).group_by_day("users.created_at").count %>
```

[image]

But i really want to the chart be stacked, not show how many subscribers was registered current day but all subscribers stacked in one day..

```
Mon -> 1
Tue -> 2(today) + 1(yesterday) = 3
Wen -> 3(today) + 3(yesterday) = 6
etc.....
```

Thanks for help!